How to install the recommended packages after having installed a package with `--no-install-recommends`?
I installed an apt package using sudo apt install <pkg> --no-install-recommends. I now realize this was a mistake, and that I should have installed the recommended packages as well. How can I install these?
ChatGPT suggested this:
apt-cache show <pkg> | grep Recommends
sudo apt install <list of packages>

However, installing them explicitly like this might not be advisable. I might be wrong, but I suspect if I were to sudo apt remove <pkg> then normally you would expect the packages which were installed as recommended packages to be either removed or removable with apt auto-remove. I think installing them explicitly will prevent this behaviour. (Do correct me if my understanding is incorrect here.)

I'm poking about a bit on an exact thing to do but the -s argument would be useful in seeing what you need without making in permanent changes

You may want to try the double arguments --reinstall --install-recommends...
